# ODBC support for Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We do have a third party Tax calculation software which natively supports Oracle and SQL Server DB as well as ODBC. Does spanner team has any plan to provide the ODBC driver that can be used with such software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're looking into providing an ODBC driver. However, we don't currently have a timeline to share.